# Why My Duplicate <ion-select> Cannot be Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I am creating a form using HTML/CSS & JavaScript and I added an "Add" button that will display the exact duplicate of the form under the original one. However, there is a problem with the ion-select element that is inside the form. In the original form, when it is clicked, it will display all the options I have predefined. However, in the duplicate form, it simply won't show anything when clicked. This doesn't happen with the input field that is also present in the form.

Here is my code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = "hello-world!";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-logic',
  templateUrl: 'logic.html'
})

export class LogicPage {
  addLogic(){
    alert('adding logic');
    const app = document.getElementById("app");
    var valueNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("logic-grid"));
    var values = valueNodes.map(valueNodes => valueNodes.innerHTML);
    var result = values.join();
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
    app.appendChild(p);
  }
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

```css
page-logic{
    ion-content {
        background: cornsilk !important;
    }
}
.ion-content{
    zoom: 2;
}

.ionic-select{
    width:200px;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100%;
    right:auto !important;
    direction: rtl !important;
    justify-content: left !important;
}

.ionic-select select::part(text) {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

input[type=number]{
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ion-content class = "ion-content">
    <ion-grid class = "logic-grid">
        <ion-row align-items-center>
            <ion-col>
                if
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-item class = "ionic-select">
                    <ion-label style = "font-size:14px;" color = "light">sensor:</ion-label>
                    <ion-select class = "ionic-select select" placeholder = "sensor var" [(ngModel)]="sensor">
                      <ion-option text-wrap value1='temp'>temp</ion-option>
                      <ion-option text-wrap value1='humid'>humidity</ion-option> 
                      <ion-option text-wrap value1='PH'>PH</ion-option> 
                      <ion-option text-wrap value1='EC'>EC</ion-option> 
                      <ion-option text-wrap value1='CO2'>CO2</ion-option> 
                      <ion-option text-wrap value1='luminance'>luminance</ion-option> 
                    </ion-select>
                  </ion-item> 
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-item class = "ionic-select">
                  <ion-label style = "font-size:14px;" color = "light">desc:</ion-label>
                  <ion-select class = "ionic-select select" placeholder = "descriptor" [(ngModel)]="desc">
                    <ion-option text-wrap value='greater'>></ion-option>
                    <ion-option text-wrap value='smaller'><</ion-option> 
                  </ion-select>
                </ion-item> 
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <label>
                  <input style = "zoom:1.5;" type = "number" placeholder = "threshold" ng-model="threshold.val">
                </label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-item class = "ionic-select">
                  <ion-label style = "font-size:14px;" color = "light">device:</ion-label>
                  <ion-select class = "ionic-select select" placeholder = "device" [(ngModel)]="device">
                    <ion-option text-wrap value2='fan'>fan</ion-option>
                    <ion-option text-wrap value2='pump(PH)'>pump PH</ion-option> 
                    <ion-option text-wrap value2='pump(NU)'>pump NU</ion-option>
                    <ion-option text-wrap value2='compressor'>compressor</ion-option>  
                    <ion-option text-wrap value2='light'>light</ion-option> 
                  </ion-select>
                </ion-item> 
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-item class = "ionic-select">
                  <ion-label style = "font-size:14px;" color = "light">on/off:</ion-label>
                  <ion-select class = "ionic-select select" placeholder = "on/off" [(ngModel)]="onoff">
                    <ion-option text-wrap value3='on'>on</ion-option>
                    <ion-option text-wrap value3='off'>off</ion-option> 
                  </ion-select>
                </ion-item> 
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                for 
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <label>
                  <input size = "10" style = "zoom:1.5;" type = "number" placeholder = "seconds" ng-model="duration.val">
                </label>
              </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <div id = "app"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script src = "logic.ts"></script>
        </ion-grid>
    <button style="zoom:1.5;" (click)="addLogic()">ADD LOGIC</button>
</ion-content>
```

Can anyone help identify the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't process HTML added dynamically, it just adds it "as is" to the DOM, so bindings etc won't work, this is why your copied components do not function as expected.

You may need to explore [ViewContainerRef.createComponent()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent)

I found this article useful for the topic:
https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d